# How can I cut the 1st letter from a cell and add to another cell in PSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I have a long list, and I want to add the first letter into another cell with psql command.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| John | J |
| Lila | L |
| Dwane | D |
| Zaba | Z |
| Kiol | K |
| Longi | L |
| Uthe | U |
| Hell | H |

Like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `left()` postgres function to extract the first charater from a string, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). Try something like this :

```
SELECT "A header", left("A header", 1) AS "Another header"
  FROM your_table
```